# Is it possible to create a public static constructor anyway?

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio 2012 there is a rule saying that : [Static constructors should be private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182320(v=vs.110).aspx), but the compiler doesn't allow this. So anyway can we create public static constructor?

[image]

**Update:** in the link, it says "If a static constructor is not private, it can be called by code other than the system.". It drives me to this question.

Comment: The access modifier on a `static` ctor would be irrelevant because it is only (and can only) be called internally by the CLR. Thus the designers prevented it from being specified in source code, as such specification would imply control of an aspect the dev does not, in fact, control.

Comment: How were you planning on trying to call this, and why?

Comment: Per the documentation you link to "This rule is enforced by the C# and Visual Basic .NET compilers." - i.e. you can't with c# or VB.Net (but you *could* with another language, if you really wanted to)

Comment: I understand the question now. The question is not "can we make a static constructor public", it is "why does this rule exists when it is impossible to break it".

Comment: [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) - "A static constructor does not take access modifiers or have parameters."

Comment: @RowlandShaw You should make that an answer, and mention that code analysis runs on the compiled binaries, not on the source code, so it will be able to handle any type of compiled assembly from any type of programming language.

Comment: @doctorlove, I there the rule, it's different with what I have in mind. Please see this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182320%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must omit the `public`/`private` modifier:

```
public class Test
{
    static Test()
    {
    }
}
```

and in truth the concept of `private` static constructor is a little flimsy, because the static constructor is called (and can be called) only by the CLR (the runtime). So the `private` is present probably only because each method must have a modifier, not because it means anything (to make it clear: a private non-static constructor can be invoked by the class that defines it, while a static constructor can't be directly invoked by the class that defines it)

Note that technically, by writing directly IL code, you can make the static constructor `public`... Then you can call it as if it was a "normal" method... and **bad things happen**... To make it clear:

Base source code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static Test()
    {
        ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(Test).GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Single();
        Console.WriteLine("Static constructor: IsPublic: {0}, IsPrivate: {1}", ci.IsPublic, ci.IsPrivate);
    }
}
```

Compile it with Visual Studio.

From the Developer Command Prompt:

```
ildasm YourExe.exe /out:test.il
```

Change the `Main` body to

```
.entrypoint
// Code size       2 (0x2)
.maxstack  8
IL_0000:  nop

// we call manually the cctor (the static constructor)
call void Test::.cctor()
IL_0001:  ret
```

then change the `Test.cctor` signature to

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname static 
      void  .cctor() cil managed
```

(see the `public`?)

Now

```
ilasm test.il
test.exe
```

The output:

```
Static constructor: IsPublic: True, IsPrivate: False
Static constructor: IsPublic: True, IsPrivate: False
```

The static constructor has been executed twice: your call to the `.cctor` plus the automatic call that the CLR does to the `.cctor`. The check that a static constructor is run only once is done only when the static constructor is called by the CLR, not when you call it manually! :-)

Comment: @haz I have to tell the truth... I'm not sure exactly what can you do directly in IL code... Can you call a constructor with IL code?

Comment: I have no idea yet... :|

Comment: @haz Re-updated the response... Full trace of what happens

Answer (score 3):

> So anyway can we create public static constructor?

No, you cant, and you don't need to. Static constructors are not callable, and aren't used like regular constructors. They are used internally by the runtime to initialize static members of your class.

> If a static constructor is not private, it can be called by code other
>   than the system.", it drives me to this question.

Don't forget that code analysis is available for languages other than C#, where it is possible that a static constructor would be non-private. Hence why this warning exists. In C#, this could never happen.

Comment: I have the same think, but in the link it says "If a static constructor is not private, it can be called by code other than the system.", it drives me to this question.

Comment: thanks, as @xanatos details, there is an option anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

Static Constructor does not have access Modifiers. Other Static elements do.

We can have static classes, fields, property and methods denoted with access modifier. But if you do so with static constructor:

```
//Static class with Access Modifier
public class SomeClass
{
    //Static Field with Access Modifier
    public static int intstatic = 0;

    //Static Property with Access Modifier
    public static string StaticProperty { get; set; }

    //Trying to declare static Constructor with Access Modifier
    public static SomeClass()
    { }

    //Static Method with Access Modifier
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(intstatic);
    }
}
```

It will result in compilation error.

"Access modifiers are not allowed on static constructors"

Haz, this will help you. go through it, it will clear your basics.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/891433/Must-Remember-Key-Concepts-to-Keyword-Static

Comment: I have it in mind, just found one point in the link "If a static constructor is not private, it can be called by code other than the system.". But it's invisible to c# :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not make a static constructor public or explicitly private in C# or VB.NET.

You could, however, possible do it in another programming language.

So the rule is there to highlight those problems.

For C# and VB.NET the rule will have no effect since you're unable to break it.

Whether it will matter is debatable since only the CLR can call the static constructor anyway, but that is why the rule exists.

Comment: Hmm, "You could, however, possible do it in another programming language." I didn't think of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers make no sense in a static context.  This is because they can not be called by you directly, *they are called implicitly by the .NET Framework*.

What is guaranteed it that your static constructor will be executed **at some point in time before the first call to any static content**.

You have no control over when this might be, in practice, it almost invariably directly before the first time you access a static member.  Don't rely on this though.  Also, pay attention to whether your static constructor changes any state outside it's own class as this could mean some very weird, irreproachable bugs.